# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.' When I try to send a Post request to my API

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core

When I try to send a post request to my API I get AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.' I am trying to map one model to another to write to a database. See code below

```
Posting to API URL with the below json
{
  "UserId": 2,
  "Task": "test"
}
```

```
public class CreateTask
{
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Task { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Tasks
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
    }
```

```
[HttpPost("task")]
        public IActionResult CreateTask(CreateTask model)
        {
            _userService.CreateTask(model);
            return Ok(new { message = "Task Created" });
        }
```

```
public void CreateTask(CreateTask model)
        {

       private IMapper _mapper;



            // map model to new user object
            var blessing = _mapper.Map<Tasks>(model);


            // save user
            _context.Tasks.Add(Task);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I adjusted the post logic and stuff was unsuccessful, that's about as far as I got.

Comment: Please show your MapperConfiguration or MappingProfile. The exception is clear, it didn't  found the *rule* on mapping from `CreateTask` to `Tasks`.

Comment: Youre exactly right, I didnt have it defined. Thank you for the help. Apoligies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Yong Shun
I did not have my rule defined.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).